# HTML Form Submiting in two ways

Tags: javascript, html

The form - |TEXTFIELD| |DROPDOWN1| |DROPDOWN2| |SUBMIT|

The form can be submited by pressing the submit button, so thats working.

My desire here is, that if the user changes value on DROPDOWN1, but does not write anything in TEXTFIELD and does not change DROPDOWN2 value, the form submits without pressing the submit button

If you want any part of the code you may go ahead and ask, but I think It's not necessary, so I will not post it without a request

Comment: You should always include relevant code

Comment: do you want the form submit every time a field is changed?

Comment: this is not a tutorial site. fist tell us what you tried and then ask how to fix it. not complete my task free for me

Comment: +1 for @ExplosionPills request for your code.

Comment: tell DROPDOWN1 to submit the code. Or post the relevant code here so that we can tell you how

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way would be something like:

```
document.getElementById('DROPDOWN1').addEventListener('change', function () {
    if (!document.getElementById('TEXTFIELD').value &&
        !document.getElementById('DROPDOWN2').value
    ) {
        this.form.submit();
    }
});
```

Basically submit the form when the `change` event is triggered for that dropdown.

Comment: I get that I need to put my own IDs there, but as a noobie in javascript or in web designing, I must ask, where exactly do i put it?

Comment: @eLbor I just took what you had in your question.  `TEXTFIELD` is the text field, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Just call the `.submit()` method on the form when your conditions are met.

```
document.getElementById("formid").submit();
```

You will need to wrap this inside of a function that will check the values of your textfield as a `onchange` event listener.